# Use linkgenerator or Urlhelper in hosted services

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to create link in an hosted service in asp.net core 6.
I can't use urlhelper because I haven't an httpcontext, and I can't understand how to use linkgenerator without httpcontext.
In linkgenerator i have to use hoststring but I don't know how to give correct parameters to HostString.FromUriComponent.

is it possible to use linkgenerator or urlhelper in hostedservice, or the best solution is to have a setting in my application that have the base uri?
or is it possible to have the base uri of the application?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use linkgenerator or urlhelper in hostedservice, or
> the best solution is to have a setting in my application that have the
> base uri? or is it possible to have the base uri of the application?

[image]

As you may know, in hostedService we cannot access `httpContext` even `httpContextAccessor` cannot be injected within the service life time.

On top of this, both [LinkGenerator extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [HtmlTagHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for example `GetUriByAction`  or `@Url.RouteUrl` and `@Url.Action` requires URL which we used to get from the given context. As `httpcontext` are inaccessible within hosted service so you cannot do that.

However, you can post another question along with your full scenario and description containing necessary code snippet by explaining, in which aspects you need to get URL. So, we can assist on that if there would any work around for that.

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-7.0)